# Can one express the evolution of a particle with a one-parameter group of $SO(3,1)$?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, spinors, time-evolution

Can one express the evolution of a particles using a sequence of $SO(3,1)$ transformations? If yes, how?

Is it sufficient to apply $SO(3,1)$ transformations to a spinor?

$$
\psi(t) = e^{t\mathfrak{so}(3,1)}\psi(0)
$$

Comment: Time evolution is generated by the Hamiltonian operator, which ends up being one of the components of the four-momentum $P^0 = H$. In that case, time evolution is actually related to the translation group, instead of the Lorentz group.

Comment: @Gold But can you not move the particle using a sequence of Boosts?

Comment: @Gold I was able to find an answer: one applies a Lorentz transformation to the velocity, then integrates to get the position.